# Can cakephp have multiple 'content'?

Tags: cakephp

So in cakephp's layout we have the

```
$this->fetch('content')
```

right? does it mean i can only have one 'content' in one layout? I really need multiple content from multiple controller can it be done? how? please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

The layout isn't capable of pulling information from the controller. The controller is the place where the view is prepared to be placed within the layout.

When you access a CakePHP URL, it's in the following format:

`http://example.com/controller/action`

In other words, you're connecting directly to the controller, not the layout.

You use the controller to get data from the Models and then when everything is ready you set it to a view and then the view is displayed, with the layout wrapped around it. So, you only put HTML/CSS etc in your layout if you want it to appear in all of your views.

To answer your question, though, your controllers don't actually have any content. Your content is (presumably) in your database. Databases are accessed using Models and it's possible to pull data from multiple Models using a single controller, which is usually done by defining relationships between multiple Models.